# How to execute a specific scenario from Intellj Cucumber feature file?

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, cucumber

Executing a specific scenario from maven command line is working fine ,

How to execute a specific scenario using tags in Intellij where there is test runner  which is responsible extent reports  , test runner will have tags="" for passing the values from maven .

Answer (score 1):

I have in "VM options" in "Run/Debug Configuration"

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags '@fast and @check'"
```